# ERROR: Nothing RPROVIDES 'u-boot-default-env' while compiling yocto for SAMA5D2

Tags: yocto

I am developing yocto project on SAMA5D2 development board. While using bitbake command for core-image-minimal I am getting following error.

```
ERROR: Nothing RPROVIDES 'u-boot-default-env' (but /home/poky/meta/recipes-bsp/u-boot/libubootenv_0.3.1.bb RDEPENDS on or otherwise requires it)
NOTE: Runtime target 'u-boot-default-env' is unbuildable, removing...
Missing or unbuildable dependency chain was: ['u-boot-default-env']
NOTE: Runtime target 'u-boot-fw-utils' is unbuildable, removing...
Missing or unbuildable dependency chain was: ['u-boot-fw-utils', 'u-boot-default-env']
NOTE: Runtime target 'clear-once' is unbuildable, removing...
Missing or unbuildable dependency chain was: ['clear-once', 'u-boot-fw-utils', 'u-boot-default-env']
```

I have also included meta-atmel layer. I am unable to find at what step iam doing wrong any pointer would be helpful.

Thanks in Advance,
Nikhil

Comment: which meta-layer with bsp do you use?

Comment: hi, I am using meta-atmel layer, meta-phosphor, meta, meta-poky,meta-oe, meta-security layer while compiling for SAMA5D27 development board

Comment: Bitbake is not looking for u-boot-at91_2020.01.bb instead it is taking libubootenv_0.3.1.bb. how to make changes so that it should look for u-boot-at91_2020.01.bb.

Comment: Try `PREFERRED_PROVIDER_u-boot = "u-boot-at91"` and `PREFERRED_PROVIDER_virtual/bootloader = "u-boot-at91"`

Comment: I have added PREFERRED_PROVIDER_u-boot = "u-boot-at91" and PREFERRED_PROVIDER_virtual/bootloader = "u-boot-at91" in sama5d27-som1-ek-sd.conf but getting same error as above.

Comment: Sorry for my mistake in question I am building it for "bitbake obmc-phosphor-image" not core-image-minimal.

Comment: It should go to `local.conf`. I don't know what machine config you use.

Comment: i have checked by adding PREFERRED_PROVIDER_u-boot = "u-boot-at91"and PREFERRED_PROVIDER_virtual/bootloader = "u-boot-at91" in local.conf ... same error ......... meta-atmel bsp layer worked for core-image-minimal but when i am building it for bitbake obmc-phosphor-image it is giving error on u-boot ..... i think it is some how not locating u-boot-at91_2020.01.bb recipe file.